# Can't find variable: counter, in expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Been using React for a bit and wanted to try out native using expo, when I click on a button to increment a counter, I get a ReferenceError on my phone saying "Can't find variable: counter", I don't get any error on the expo gui or in VSCode, very confused.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    };
  }

  increment() {
    this.setState({ counter: (counter += 1) });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.counter}</Text>
        <Button title="Press Me" onPress={this.increment}></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

Comment: In your `increment()` method it should be `this.state.counter+1`, `counter` as a variable is not defined.

Or you can do: `const {counter} = this.state;` before your version of `this.setState()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `increment` function to

```
increment = () => {
    this.setState({
        counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });
}
```

Make sure to define your `increment` function as an arrow function otherwise you can't access it from `Button`.

```
<Button title="Press Me" onPress={this.increment}></Button>
```

Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Worked great, at first it didn't but I saw you changed the counter to this.state.counter :)

Answer (score 1):

The counter variable you are referring inside `increment` function doesn't refer to the state variable. Access the state object using `this.state.counter` and then increment it by 1.

Please update the increment function as below

```
  increment() {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter+ 1) });
  }

  <Button title="Press Me" onPress={() => this.increment()}></Button>
```

Comment: if you use the above approach, you need to bind your ```increment``` function inside the constructor.

Comment: Thanks @SDushan, But it not required in this scenario, you could use an inline call function in `onPress event`

Answer (score 1):

So there are 2 ways of doing it, either you change your increment function to a fat arrow function or bind the `this` scope of function in constructor, Its basically how `this` scope gets binded:

```
increment = () => {
    this.setState({ counter: (counter += 1) });
  }
```

another way is :

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    };
this.increment = this.increment.bind(this); // new addition
  }

  increment() {
    this.setState({ counter: (counter += 1) });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.counter}</Text>
        <Button title="Press Me" onPress={this.increment}></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it gets clear, these are the 2 ways. Feel free for doubts